# Align item to right in Tablecellview using Autolayout or springs and struts

Tags: ios, iphone, autolayout

Im having this problem where I simply want to align a UILabel to right of a table viewcell. I have tried both approaches of Autolayout and Springs and struts but neither of them is working. When I run the app on a larger screen size, the cell does resize properly but the UIlabel doesn't align to the right of the tableview cell. What is the proper way to handle this?

For knowledge, I will like to know solution of both approaches.

Note : Its a tableViewController not a custom view controller
[image: My settings for Using Struts and Springs]

[image: My settings for Using Autolayout]

[image: How it shows on iPhone 6]

Comment: i think the problem is you doesn't set any constraints to your tableview.....pin all edges of tableview..

Comment: Im using tableview controller. I have tested and confirmed - the table does resize properly.

Comment: ok...if tableview controller is there then its fine...and i check your constraints and its working properly on my view....is there any view inside cell?

Answer (score 0):

You have to set first tableview's constraint with all side.